# Descriptive statistics of typos in tab-delimited dataset

Tags: excel, vba, statistics

I'm trying to write a macro in Excel to find the average and standard deviation of typos in a natural language text data set in tab delimited format (a set of Tweets, specifically). I can find the average in Word easy enough by doing a CTRL+F for tabs to get number of messages and looking at the total number of errors listed in SpellCheck. This doesn't help with SD though. Purpose-built language analytics software can't search for general non-words without counting things like disfluencies ("ugh", "ach") as far as I can tell.

I can't figure out how to include spelling and grammatical errors in the Excel macro or how to break them apart by cell.

The data set is big enough that I don't mind minor inaccuracies (they shouldn't vary systematically between conditions).

This tool could be adjusted to evaluate basic writing skills or to compare non-standard uses of English in sufficiently large writing samples. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since Word has the ability built-in to detect spelling and grammatical errors, you could create a cross-program script in Excel. You would just have Word do the language processing piece, and Excel do the statistical analysis. You would need to enable the Microsoft Word 15.0 Object Library from the Tools > References menu in the Excel VBE.

VBA in Word allows you to detect if there's a spelling error. See this link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171830(v=office.11).aspx

The logic behind the code would be:

1. From Excel, open a new Word document.
2. For each Tweet, copy the content of the cell and paste into the blank Word doc.
3. Have Word scan the document for errors, returning True if detected, False if not.
4. In Excel, if you get a True value, insert a 1 next to the tweet, and a 2 if False.
5. Clear all content from the Word doc.
6. Go to the next tweet (next cell) in Excel, and do steps 2-6 until each tweet has a 1 or 2 next to it.

You should be able to correlate the occurrences of language errors with other variables, such as, e.g., the Twitter handles.

Essentially, have each program do what it does best.